# Boxed text between pages

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-breaking, boxes, mdframed

I've made boxed text into a manuscript using `tikz` by following the example in [texamples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/boxes-with-text-and-math/), it works like a charm as long as the box is short enough to fit into a page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

% Define box and box title style
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=red, text=white]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {A fancy title};
\node[fancytitle, rounded corners] at (box.east) {$\clubsuit$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\end{document}
```

**Questions**

Is there a way to extend the code so that the box break (automatically) through pages?

I just found the `mdframed` package, 
How could I combine the two packages?

Comment: Could you mock up a simple document showing the situation you have, and post it here, to give a starting point?

Comment: And for boxes spanning multiple pages, where should the clover (`\clubsuit`) appear?

Comment: Please see my updated answer for the inclusion of a counter.

Comment: For information. Many thanks.
Faouzi Bellalouna

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165088/boxed-text-between-pages-in-arabic-rightmargin-with-tikz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1st version: *general* box with `mdframed`.**

You don't need to `combine` both packages, just load `mdframed` with `framemethod=TikZ` and look at the example 5 in [`mdframed-example-tikz.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed-example-tikz.pdf). I still don't completely understand how it works, but after some trial and error test I produced next code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}

\tikzstyle{titregris} =
    [draw=red, thick, fill=red,% 
        text=white, rectangle,  
        right,minimum height=.7cm]

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{exercisebackground}{100bp}{color(0bp)=(green!40);color(100bp)=(black!5)}

\newcounter{exercise}

\renewcommand*\theexercise{Exercise~n\arabic{exercise}}


\makeatletter
\def\mdf@@exercisepoints{}
\define@key{mdf}{exercisepoints}{
    \def\mdf@exercisepoints{#1}
}
\def\mdf@@myboxedtitle{}
\define@key{mdf}{myboxedtitle}{
    \def\mdf@myboxedtitle{#1}
}
\mdfdefinestyle{exercisestyle}{%
    outerlinewidth=1em,%
    outerlinecolor=white,%
    leftmargin=-1em,%
    rightmargin=-1em,%
    middlelinewidth=1.2pt,%
    roundcorner=5pt,%
    linecolor=red,%
    apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={blue!30}}},
    innertopmargin=1.2\baselineskip,
    skipabove={\dimexpr0.5\baselineskip+\topskip\relax},
    skipbelow={-1em},
    needspace=3\baselineskip,
    frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
    settings={\global\stepcounter{exercise}},
    singleextra={%
        \node[titregris,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
            {~\mdf@frametitlefont{\mdf@myboxedtitle}~};
},%
    firstextra={%
\node[titregris,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{\mdf@myboxedtitle}~};
},
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{mdframed}[style=exercisestyle,myboxedtitle={Hello}]
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

**2nd version: *exercise* box with `mdframed`.**

As I've told, previous code was taken from an example at `mdframed` documentation. This example is supposed to be used for exercises and I didn't change original names. Now, if you want to type exercises with this format we can come back to the original code, clean it a little bit and obtain:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\tikzstyle{titlered} =
    [draw=red, thick, fill=red,% 
        text=white, rectangle,  
        right, minimum height=.7cm]

\newcounter{exercise}

\renewcommand*\theexercise{Exercise~\arabic{exercise}}

\makeatletter
\mdfdefinestyle{exercisestyle}{%
    outerlinewidth=1em,%
    outerlinecolor=white,%
    leftmargin=-1em,%
    rightmargin=-1em,%
    middlelinewidth=1.2pt,%
    roundcorner=5pt,%
    linecolor=red,%
    backgroundcolor=blue!20,
    innertopmargin=1.2\baselineskip,
    skipabove={\dimexpr0.5\baselineskip+\topskip\relax},
    skipbelow={-1em},
    needspace=3\baselineskip,
    frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
    settings={\global\stepcounter{exercise}},
    singleextra={%
        \node[titlered,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
            {~\mdf@frametitlefont{\theexercise}~};},%
    firstextra={%
            \node[titlered,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
                    {~\mdf@frametitlefont{\theexercise}~};},
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\SomeText}{%
    To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
    equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
    For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
}

\newenvironment{MyExercise}%
{\begin{mdframed}[style=exercisestyle]}{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
   \begin{MyExercise}
       \SomeText

       \SomeText
   \end{MyExercise}

   \begin{MyExercise}
       \SomeText

       \SomeText

       \SomeText
   \end{MyExercise}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**3rd version: *general* and *exercise* box with `tcolorbox`.**

Just for completion, I'd like to add a solution made with [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package. With recent versions it's possible to make `breakable` framed boxes with it.

This package provides several libraries to modify it's default behavior, we will need three of them:

1. `breakable`: to allow boxes to automatically break between pages.
2. `skins`: to add some overlays over regular boxes.
3. `hooks`: to be able of using some special hooks in our code.

Next code includes some comments to explain how to use it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins,breakable,hooks]{tcolorbox}

\newcounter{myexercise}

% Definition of some styles and parameters for
% tcolorboxes
\tcbset{%
% Title boxes will be added with overlays
  fancytitle/.code={%
    \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\pgfkeysalso{%
        top=\baselineskip,
        overlay unbroken and first app = {%
        \node[rectangle, draw=red, fill=red,  
              anchor=west,font=\color{white}]
         at ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west)%
        {\strut#1};},
       enlarge top by = \baselineskip,
       enlarge top at break by= 0mm,
    }}},
% This is our boxes style
  fancybox/.style 2 args = {%
    breakable, enhanced, colback=blue!20,
    colframe=red, width=#1,
    fancytitle={#2},pad at break=2mm},
  fancybox/.default = {.5\textwidth}{}%
}

% This command creates a new environment called
% FancyBox which uses previously defined fancybox 
% style
\newtcolorbox{FancyBox}[2][.5\textwidth]{%
    fancybox={#1}{#2}}

% This command creates a new environment called
% FancyExercise which uses previously defined 
% fancybox style with an automatic enumerated
% title.
\newtcolorbox{FancyExercise}[1][.5\textwidth]{%
    code={\stepcounter{myexercise}},
     fancybox={#1}{Exercise~\arabic{myexercise}}}   


\newcommand{\SomeText}{To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

% Example of a FancyExercise
\begin{FancyExercise}[.75\textwidth]
        \SomeText
\end{FancyExercise}

% Example of a FancyExercise with default width
\begin{FancyExercise}
        \SomeText
\end{FancyExercise}

% Example of a FancyBox with a mandatory title
\begin{FancyBox}[\textwidth]{This is a tcolorbox}
        \SomeText
\end{FancyBox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ignasi, it woked like a charm! However, I have a question about the exercise counter. Could you include an example with the exercise counter working? Cheers!

Comment: @gonzalo-medina Thank you for your help, your solutions have been great. However, I am having problems with boxed larger than two pages (using book class)... I'm getting one boxed page, a blank page, a boxed page, and so on. Do you know a solution for this behaviour?

Comment: @Dox: I've tested with `\documentclass{book}` and `\begin{MyExercise}\lipsum[1-20]\end{MyExercise}`. It produces a box starting on page 1 and finishing on page 5 without any blank page.

Answer (score 5):

Heres' one possible solution; the `Fancybox` environment has one optional argument, for the width of the box (default=`0.5\textwidth`), and a mandatory argument for the title of the box (provision is made in the case no title is given (see example below)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newenvironment{Fancybox}[2][.5\textwidth]
{%
  \ifstrempty{#2}%
    {}%
    {\mdfsetup{%
      frametitle={%
      \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
      \node[draw=red,anchor=east,rectangle,fill=red,font=\color{white}]
        {\strut#2};}}%
    }%
  \mdfsetup{
    skipabove=\topskip,
    skipbelow=\topskip,
    innertopmargin=10pt,
    linecolor=red,%
    innerlinewidth=0.8pt,
    topline=true,
    backgroundcolor=blue!20,
    frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,
    roundcorner=5pt,
    singleextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in node[fill=red,font=\color{white}] at (P|-0,0.5*\y2+0.5*\y1) {$\clubsuit$};}
  }
  \begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=#1]\relax%
}
{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Fancybox}{A fancy title}
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{Fancybox}

\begin{Fancybox}[\textwidth]{Another fancy title}
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{Fancybox}

\begin{Fancybox}[4cm]{}
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{Fancybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since no information was given in the question about the desired position of the `\clubsuit` decoration in case the environment spans more than one page, I only used the decoration in `singleextra`, so it will only appear if the frame doesn't contain a page break (in any case, this seemed a valid choice). If other bahaviour is desired, this can be easily achieved using the other ...extra family of keys (refer to the `mdframed` documentation for details).

A request has been made to include a counter and have a fixed "Exercise" title; this makes things even easier: a simple modification is enough; this new code also adds \allowdisplaybreaks (suggested by **Marco Daniel** to have better breaking points in case displayed math is involved):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcounter{exe}

\newenvironment{Fancybox}[1][.5\textwidth]
{%
    \stepcounter{exe}%
  \mdfsetup{%
      frametitle={%
      \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
      \node[draw=red,anchor=east,rectangle,fill=red,font=\color{white}]
        {\strut Exercise~\theexe};},%
    skipabove=\topskip,
    skipbelow=\topskip,
    innertopmargin=10pt,
    linecolor=red,%
    innerlinewidth=0.8pt,
    topline=true,
    backgroundcolor=blue!20,
    frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,
    roundcorner=5pt,
    singleextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in node[fill=red,font=\color{white}] at (P|-0,0.5*\y2+0.5*\y1) {$\clubsuit$};}
  }
  \begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=#1]\allowdisplaybreaks\relax%
}
{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Fancybox}
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{Fancybox}

\begin{Fancybox}[\textwidth]
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{Fancybox}

\begin{Fancybox}[4cm]
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{Fancybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @gonzalo-medina, Inspired solution to the problem!

Comment: @ignasi Thank you for your help, your solutions have been great. However, I am having problems with boxed larger than two pages (using book class)... I'm getting one boxed page, a blank page, a boxed page, and so on. Do you know a solution for this behaviour?

Comment: @Dox I've done some tests, but I haven't been able to reproduce the problem mentioned. Open a new (follow-up) question providing a minimal working example illustrating the problem.