# boxed text between pages in arabic, rightmargin with tikz

Tags: boxes, mdframed, tikz-styles, polyglossia, arabic

First, I want to thank the members of the discussion of the message 
[Boxed text between pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115576/boxed-text-between-pages) 
which was very  interesting for my use, so I got a macro in arabic for my examples (which is right-to-left language), strongly induced from the "2nd version: exercise box with mdframed." (I am finishing a book of probability in arabic...)
With some transformations, what you can see in my file-example (where I put two cpies of the same frame, mixing of arabic and english, for watching you some beauty of Latex and tools, what I hope that you see, even if you don't understand the arabic...\RL means right-to-left, and \LR the inverse), I got a good macro and all seems good... else the commands leftmargin=, rightmargin=, which have absolutely no effect in my file, you can put all the values that you want it does not change anything, and you can see on he example that the result is very bad. Someone knows the reason of that and the way to make it as usual? Many thanks.
Faouzi

Here's my file-example

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}%{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}





%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{slashbox} % PROBLEME
%%\usepackage{diagbox} %% POUR REMPLACER SLASHBOX ?

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{minitoc} 

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{fmultico}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}




\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Amiri}
%%\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Amiri}



\tikzstyle{titlered} =
    [draw=black, thick, scale=.7, fill=white,% 
        line width=0.1pt, text=black, rectangle,  
        left, minimum height=.5cm]


\newcounter{example}
\renewcommand*\theexample{\RL{مثال~\arabic{section}\alph{example}}}


\makeatletter
\mdfdefinestyle{examplestyle}{%
    outerlinewidth=1em,%
    outerlinecolor=white,%
    leftmargin=-1em,%
    rightmargin=-1em,%
    middlelinewidth=1.2pt,%
%    roundcorner=5pt,%
    linecolor=gray!20,%
    backgroundcolor=white,%
    innertopmargin=1.2\baselineskip,
%    skipabove={\dimexpr0.5\baselineskip+\topskip\relax},
    skipabove={\dimexpr1\baselineskip\relax},
    skipbelow={0em},
    needspace=3\baselineskip,
    frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
    settings={\global\stepcounter{example}},
    firstextra={%
            \node[titlered,xshift=-1cm] at (P-|P) %
                    {\RL{~{\mdf@frametitlefont{\theexample}}~}};},%
    singleextra={%
%        \node[titlered,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
         \node[titlered,xshift=-1cm] at (P-|P) %
            {\RL{~{\mdf@frametitlefont{\theexample}}~}};}
}
\makeatother



\newenvironment{example}%
{\begin{mdframed}[style=examplestyle]}{\end{mdframed}}





\newcommand{\SomeText}{%
    To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
    equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
    For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
}

\newcommand{\SomeOtherText}{%
    To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
    equations are needed:
        \begin{align*}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align*}
    For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align*}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align*}
}



\begin{document}

    \begin{example}
    \SomeText

تحديد ما إذا كان الفريق قد تعامل بصفة جيدة مع كل المباريات، تلك التي من المرجح أن
يفوز بها، و المباريات الأخرى. يمكن التعمق في هذه المسألة عبر حساب عدد سلسلات النجاح ثم التثبت مما إذا كانت هذه النتيجة محتملة أم لا، عندما كل ال 
$(n + m)!/(n! \ m!)$ 
ترتيبات ل
 $n$ 
 نجاح و 
 $m$ 
 خسارة، متساوية الاحتمالات...

المتغيرات العشوائية، التي قيمها تنتمي إلى مجموعة 
\textit{على الأكثر قابلة للعد (أو  تعدادية)}
  (أي تعدادية أو منتهية)، تسمى المتغيرات العشوائية المنفصلة، أو المتقطعة. لمتغير عشوائي منفصل 
 $X$، 
 نعرف ب\textit{دالة الأوزان الاحتمالية} 
 ل $X$ 
 $p(a)$ ،
\begin{equation*}
p (a) = P \{X = a\}
\end{equation*}
دالة الأوزان الاحتمالية 
 $p(a)$ 
 هي دالة موجبة لقيم  
 $a$، 
 على الأكثر تعدادية. 
  أي أن، إذا 
   $X$ 
   يأخذ واحدة من القيم 
    $x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots$، 
    فإن  
\begin{alignat*}{4}
&p(x_{i}) \geq 0 &&\quad \ i = 1, 2, \ldots\\
&p(x) = 0 &&\quad\mbox{\RL{ لكل القيم الأخرى ل 
    $x$ } }
\end{alignat*}

\LR{\SomeOtherText} 


   \end{example}

    \begin{example}
    \SomeText

تحديد ما إذا كان الفريق قد تعامل بصفة جيدة مع كل المباريات، تلك التي من المرجح أن
يفوز بها، و المباريات الأخرى. يمكن التعمق في هذه المسألة عبر حساب عدد سلسلات النجاح ثم التثبت مما إذا كانت هذه النتيجة محتملة أم لا، عندما كل ال 
$(n + m)!/(n! \ m!)$ 
ترتيبات ل
 $n$ 
 نجاح و 
 $m$ 
 خسارة، متساوية الاحتمالات...

المتغيرات العشوائية، التي قيمها تنتمي إلى مجموعة \textit{على الأكثر قابلة للعد (أو  تعدادية)}
  (أي تعدادية أو منتهية)، تسمى المتغيرات العشوائية المنفصلة، أو المتقطعة. لمتغير عشوائي منفصل 
 $X$، 
 نعرف ب\textit{دالة الأوزان الاحتمالية} 
 ل $X$ 
 $p(a)$ ،
\begin{equation*}
p (a) = P \{X = a\}
\end{equation*}
دالة الأوزان الاحتمالية 
 $p(a)$ 
 هي دالة موجبة لقيم  
 $a$، 
 على الأكثر تعدادية. 
  أي أن، إذا 
   $X$ 
   يأخذ واحدة من القيم 
    $x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots$، 
    فإن  
\begin{alignat*}{4}
&p(x_{i}) \geq 0 &&\quad \ i = 1, 2, \ldots\\
&p(x) = 0 &&\quad\mbox{\RL{ لكل القيم الأخرى ل 
    $x$ } }
\end{alignat*}

\LR{\SomeOtherText} 


   \end{example}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Just a note: I have got no compilation error (XeLaTeX), the `slashbox` package is downloadable from http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/slashbox/.