# Would like a mdframed environment style with framed title box inset above without fill

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

Here's a slight tweak to one of the `mdframed` examples that produces a framed title inset above the theorem box

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{svgcolor}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newcounter{Lemma}[section]
\newenvironment{Lemma}[1][]{%
  \stepcounter{Lemma}%
  \ifstrempty{#1}%
  {\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
      \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
      \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
    {\strut \color{DarkOliveGreen}{Lemma}~\theLemma};}}
  }%
  {\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
      \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
      \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
    {\strut \color{DarkOliveGreen}{Lemma}~\theLemma:~\color{Maroon}{#1}};}}%
  }%
  \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
            linewidth=1pt,topline=true,%
            frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}
  \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
  }{\end{mdframed}}


\begin{document}

\begin{Lemma}[Distribution of inner products]\label{thm:stokesTheoremGeometricAlgebraII:1420}
Given two blades $A_s, B_r$ with grades subject to $0 < r < s$, and a vector $b$, the inner product distributes according to
\begin{equation*}
    A_s \cdot \left( b \wedge B_r \right) = \left( A_s \cdot b \right) \cdot B_r.
\end{equation*}
\end{Lemma}

\end{document}
```

This looks like:

[image: lemma box]

I'd like the title box to have a framed look instead of filled, but am unsure how to do that.  There are examples, like 
" [Example 5 – complex example with TikZ](http://www.math.mun.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf), where there is a distinct frame around the title, but that example isn't a good one for me to attempt to build from since it does a lot that I don't want (like overriding the Exercise environment).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
  {\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
      \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
      \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
    {\strut \color{DarkOliveGreen}{Lemma}~\theLemma};}}
  }%
  {\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
      \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
      \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
    {\strut \color{DarkOliveGreen}{Lemma}~\theLemma:~\color{Maroon}{#1}};}}%
  }%
```

to

```
  {\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
      \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
      \node[line width=1pt,anchor=east,rectangle,draw=blue!20,fill=white]
    {\strut \color{DarkOliveGreen}{Lemma}~\theLemma};}}
  }%
  {\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
      \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
      \node[line width=1pt,anchor=east,rectangle,draw=blue!20,fill=white]
    {\strut \color{DarkOliveGreen}{Lemma}~\theLemma:~\color{Maroon}{#1}};}}%
  }%
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{svgcolor}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newcounter{Lemma}[section]
\newenvironment{Lemma}[1][]{%
  \stepcounter{Lemma}%
  \ifstrempty{#1}%
  {\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
      \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
      \node[line width=1pt,anchor=east,rectangle,draw=blue!20,fill=white]
    {\strut \color{DarkOliveGreen}{Lemma}~\theLemma};}}
  }%
  {\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
      \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
      \node[line width=1pt,anchor=east,rectangle,draw=blue!20,fill=white]
    {\strut \color{DarkOliveGreen}{Lemma}~\theLemma:~\color{Maroon}{#1}};}}%
  }%
  \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
            linewidth=1pt,topline=true,%
            frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}
  \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
  }{\end{mdframed}}


\begin{document}

\begin{Lemma}[Distribution of inner products]\label{thm:stokesTheoremGeometricAlgebraII:1420}
Given two blades $A_s, B_r$ with grades subject to $0 < r < s$, and a vector $b$, the inner product distributes according to
\begin{equation*}
    A_s \cdot \left( b \wedge B_r \right) = \left( A_s \cdot b \right) \cdot B_r.
\end{equation*}
\end{Lemma}

\begin{Lemma}
Given two blades $A_s, B_r$ with grades subject to $0 < r < s$, and a vector $b$, the inner product distributes according to
\begin{equation*}
    A_s \cdot \left( b \wedge B_r \right) = \left( A_s \cdot b \right) \cdot B_r.
\end{equation*}
\end{Lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks.  btw.  Looks like the first \node line should be:

\node[anchor=east,rectangle,draw=blue!20,fill=white]

(ie. still want a box for an unnamed, but still numbered begin/end block).

Comment: @PeeterJoot ooops! You're right. I forgot to update the code there. I've fixed it.

Comment: @PeeterJoot I introduced another minor modification, so now the rules used in the frame for the title have the same thickness as the rules used for the general frame.

Comment: Very nice, that looks better.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is explicity about [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) but in case somebody could be interested in similar theorem environments, package [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) is an alternative.

Theorem and similar environments have been available since initial `tcolorbox` versions, but recent ones (v 3.05) introduced facilities to easily place titles like OP wanted. It was already possible with more complex code as can be seen in [Boxed text between pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115605/1952), but now it's easier to do it.

`tcolorbox` macro

```
\newtcbtheorem[<init options>]{<name>}{<display name>}{<options>}{<prefix>}
```

defines a new theorem environment called `name` which will show `display name` in its title, the whole format will be controlled with `options` and labels for further reference will be preceded by a `prefix`. Therefore macro

```
\newtcbtheorem{myLemma}{Lemma}{lemmastyle}{thm}
```

defines a new `myLemma` box, auto enumerated, titled `Lemma <num>` with aspect defined in `lemmastyle` and referenced with labels `thm:anylabel`. With this macro help, theorems in text are defined with:

```
\begin{myLemma}{<lemma description>}{<possible label>}
...
\end{myLemma}
```

Next code shows an example which tries to mimmic Gonzalo's results. There are some little differences with inner margins but the general aspect is quite similar.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
    lemmastyle/.style={enhanced, colback=white, colframe=blue!20, arc=0pt, 
                       fonttitle=\bfseries, description color=Maroon,  
                       colbacktitle=white, coltitle=DarkOliveGreen,    
                       top=\tcboxedtitleheight,
                       boxed title style={arc=0pt},
                       attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,
                                                       xshift=4mm}%
                      },
}

\newtcbtheorem{myLemma}{Lemma}{lemmastyle}{thm}

\begin{document}

\begin{myLemma}{Distribution of inner products}{stokesTheoremGeometricAlgebraII:1420}
Given two blades $A_s, B_r$ with grades subject to $0 < r < s$, 
and a vector $b$, the inner product distributes according to
\begin{equation*}
    A_s \cdot \left( b \wedge B_r \right) = \left( A_s \cdot b \right) \cdot B_r.
\end{equation*}
\end{myLemma}

\begin{myLemma}{}{}
Given two blades $A_s, B_r$ with grades subject to $0 < r < s$, 
and a vector $b$, the inner product distributes according to
\begin{equation*}
    A_s \cdot \left( b \wedge B_r \right) = \left( A_s \cdot b \right) \cdot B_r.
\end{equation*}
\end{myLemma}
\end{document}
```

[image]