# Coloured box with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, boxes

I'd like to break a coloured box when the page which contains it breaks... here is an example which shows this issue:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,enumerate,makeidx,mathrsfs,graphicx,epsfig,fancyhdr,pst-grad,pst-plot,tikz-cd,tikz}
\usepackage{ccfonts,MnSymbol,colortbl}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=blue, fill=blue!15, thick, rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=blue, rounded corners, text=white, inner sep=6pt]
\tikzstyle{fancyend} =[draw=blue, fill=white, thick, rounded corners, text=blue]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
\end{minipage}};
\node[fancytitle,right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Teorema Fundamental del C\'alculo};
\node[fancyend] at (box.south east) {$\diamondsuit$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and it looks like this:[image: Box which doesn't fit page height]

Comment: I think, the `mdframed` package can do this as well.

Comment: If you want to write theorems inside colored and framed boxes `tcolorbox` is another alternative. You can see an example of using it in [Would like a mdframed environment style with framed title box inset above without fill](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184530/1952). Of course, some more (and very usefull) information in [`tcolorbox`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another `tcolorbox` answer. I tried to mimic the colors and design of your example. Additionally, I used a numbered environment which you may want to have.

Note that you should use the most recent version of `tcolorbox`, i.e. `3.05 (2014/05/28)`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,enumerate,makeidx,mathrsfs,graphicx,epsfig,fancyhdr,pst-grad,pst-plot,tikz-cd,tikz}
\usepackage{ccfonts,MnSymbol,colortbl}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}

\usepackage[skins,breakable,theorems]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem{theorema}{Theorema}{enhanced jigsaw,breakable,
  colframe=blue,colback=blue!15!white,boxrule=1pt,
  attach boxed title to top left={xshift=10pt,yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
  boxed title style={interior empty},
  underlay unbroken and last={\node[draw=blue,fill=white,thick,rounded corners,text=blue] at (frame.south east) {$\diamondsuit$};},
  enlarge bottom finally by=2.5mm,pad at break=2mm}{theo}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorema}{Teorema Fundamental del C\'alculo}{fundamental}
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
\end{theorema}

\begin{theorema}{Pythagorean theorem}{pythagoras}
The Pythagorean equation is
\[a^2+b^2=c^2.\]
\end{theorema}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** To get the same thing without the numbering, you can use the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,enumerate,makeidx,mathrsfs,graphicx,epsfig,fancyhdr,pst-grad,pst-plot,tikz-cd,tikz}
\usepackage{ccfonts,MnSymbol,colortbl}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}

\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{enhanced jigsaw,breakable,
  title={#1},colframe=blue,colback=blue!15!white,boxrule=1pt,
  attach boxed title to top left={xshift=10pt,yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
  boxed title style={interior empty},
  underlay unbroken and last={\node[draw=blue,fill=white,thick,rounded corners,text=blue] at (frame.south east) {$\diamondsuit$};},
  enlarge bottom finally by=2.5mm,pad at break=2mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{Teorema Fundamental del C\'alculo}
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{Pythagorean theorem}
The Pythagorean equation is
\[a^2+b^2=c^2.\]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks more as I want, but let me check if I can write it unnumbered, I'll let you know later... Thanks!

Comment: @Romeo I updated my answer with an unnumbered version of the same thing...

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas, it worked just as I wanted! But I have one more question: for the Theorem case, how can I change the environment to have theorems numbered by section, instead by chapter?

Comment: Problem solved, I just have to ask the following in the environment:   \newtcbtheorem[number within=section]...

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
```

And custom everything with the multiple options of this package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,enumerate,makeidx,mathrsfs,graphicx,epsfig,fancyhdr,pst-grad,pst-plot,tikz-cd,tikz}
\usepackage{ccfonts,MnSymbol,colortbl}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[%
    colback=red!5!white,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    title=My nice heading,
    breakable]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
El primer teorema fundamental del c\'alculo dice que si $f$ es continua en el intervalo cerrado $[a,b]$ y $F$ es la integral indefinida de $f$ sobre $[a,b]$, entonces
\[\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a). \]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Uwe and Tarass, I'm testing both options... they seem to be better than the first one I had.