# Customize a theorem environment in ConTeXt

Tags: theorems, context

I have seen a post ([Editing theorem environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235547/editing-theorem-environments)) explaining how to customize the `theorem` environment in LaTeX, using the `thmbox` package.

[image: original]

I would like the same output for my document but I only use ConTeXt and I am not an expert on TeX. Can someone tell me how to achieve this from scratch or using the ConTeXt mechanisms? Also, I would prefer if:

- the rule were thicker
- the corner were rounded
- the bottom rule spanned the whole page
- the environnement could split across pages

Like this :

[image: modified]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution. Let's start with a version that doesn't break across pages. We'll fix that later.

First, let's try to get the basic layout without the frames. Unlike the other solutions, I don't move the theorem head to the right, rather I move the theorem body to the left.

```
\defineenumeration[THEOREMenumeration]
                  [
                    text=Theorem ,%Space after Theorem is delibrate
                    title=yes,
                    alternative=hanging, 
                    titlestyle=boldslanted, % or bolditalic
                    style=slanted, % or italic
                    width=fit,
                 ]


\define\starttheorem
  {\dosingleargument\dostarttheorem}

\def\dostarttheorem[#1]%
    {\startTHEOREMenumeration[#1]%
     \crlf
     }

\define\stoptheorem
    {\stopTHEOREMenumeration
    }


\starttext
\input ward
\starttheorem[title={Riemann-Lebesgue}]
  \input ward
  Pour tout $f \in L^1({\Bbb T})$, on a
  \startformula
    \lim_{|n| \to ∞} c_n(f) = 0
  \stopformula
\stoptheorem

\input knuth
\stoptext
```

which gives:

[image]

Now all we need is the frame. To get the bottom rule around the theorem head, you can use:

```
\defineenumeration[THEOREMenumeration]
                  [
                    ....
                    headcommand=\THEOREMframed,
                 ]
```

where `\THEOREMframed` is defined as:

```
  \defineframed     [THEOREMframed]
                    [
                      frame=off,
                      bottomframe=on,
                      location=low,
                      rulethickness=2bp,
                    ]
```

which gives:

[image]

The rule overlaps with the next line, but we'll fix this later.

Now, to get the frame around the theorem body, change the definitions of `\starttheorem` and `\stoptheorem` to:

```
\def\dostarttheorem[#1]%
    {\startTHEOREMenumeration[#1]%
     \startTHEOREMframedtext
     }

\define\stoptheorem
    {\stopTHEOREMframedtext
     \stopTHEOREMenumeration
    }
```

where `THEOREMframedtext` is defined as:

```
\defineframedtext [THEOREMframedtext]
                  [
                    offset=0pt,
                    loffset=1em,
                    boffset=1em,
                    corner=15,
                    width=broad,
                    rulethickness=2bp,
                    before=,
                    after=,
                    strut=no,
                  ]
```

which gives:

[image]

Note that the theorem is now too broad. We can fix that by using:

```
\defineframedtext [THEOREMframedtext]
                  [ 
                  ....
                    width=\dimexpr(\hsize-\framedparameter{loffset} -\framedparameter{rulethickness})\relax,
                  ....
                  ]
```

Here is the complete code:

```
\defineenumeration[THEOREMenumeration]
                  [
                    text=Theorem ,%Space after Theorem is delibrate
                    title=yes,
                    alternative=hanging, 
                    titlestyle=boldslanted, % or bolditalic
                    style=slanted, % or italic
                    width=fit,
                    headcommand=\THEOREMframed,
                 ]

  \defineframed     [THEOREMframed]
                    [
                      frame=off,
                      bottomframe=on,
                      location=low,
                      rulethickness=2bp,
                    ]

\defineframedtext [THEOREMframedtext]
                  [
                    offset=0pt,
                    loffset=1em,
                    boffset=1em,
                    corner=15,
                    width=\dimexpr(\hsize-\framedparameter{loffset} -\framedparameter{rulethickness})\relax,
                    rulethickness=2bp,
                    before=,
                    after=,
                    strut=no,
                  ]



\define\starttheorem
  {\dosingleargument\dostarttheorem}

\def\dostarttheorem[#1]%
    {\startTHEOREMenumeration[#1]%
     \startTHEOREMframedtext
     }

\define\stoptheorem
    {\stopTHEOREMframedtext
     \stopTHEOREMenumeration
    }


\starttext
\input ward
\starttheorem[title={Riemann-Lebesgue}]
  \input ward
  Pour tout $f \in L^1({\Bbb T})$, on a
  \startformula
    \lim_{|n| \to ∞} c_n(f) = 0
  \stopformula
\stoptheorem

\input knuth
\stoptext
```

Now, to make sure that the body can split across the page, we need to change the `framedtext` with a `textbackground`. The keys of `textbackgroud` are different from that of `framedtext`. We start with:

```
\definetextbackground [THEOREMframedtext]
                  [
                    mp=ellframe,
                    location=paragraph,
                    leftoffset=1em,
                    topoffset=1.5ex,
                    bottomoffset=1em,
                    rightoffset=0pt,
                    rulethickness=2bp,
                    framecolor=black,
                    before=,
                    after=,
                    strut=no,
                  ]
```

[image]

Now all we need to do is define the metapost graphic `ellframe` that draws the L-shaped frame. Before we do that, we need to decide what happens when the theorem overflows a page: should we draw L-shaped frames on both pages, or should we draw a straight line on the first page and an L-shaped frame on the second? What happens in the unlikely scenario that the theorem spans three pages? ConTeXt makes it easy to write code specialized to each scenario.

```
\startuseMPgraphic{ellframe}
  begingroup;
    interim linecap := butt ;
    for i=1 upto nofmultipars :
      if multikind[i] = "single" :
          draw ( ulcorner multipars[i] -- 
               ( llcorner multipars[i] + (0, boxlineradius )){down} ..
               {right}(llcorner multipars[i] + (boxlineradius, 0) ) --
                 lrcorner multipars[i] )
      elseif multikind[i] = "first" :
          draw leftboundary   multipars[i] 
      elseif multikind[i]= "middle" :
          draw leftboundary  multipars[i] 
      elseif multikind[i]= "last" :
          draw ( ulcorner multipars[i] -- 
               ( llcorner multipars[i] + (0, boxlineradius )){down} ..
               {right}(llcorner multipars[i] + (boxlineradius, 0) ) --
                 lrcorner multipars[i] )
      fi 
      boxlineoptions withpen pencircle scaled boxlinewidth ;
    endfor ;
  endgroup;
\stopuseMPgraphic
```

This is the output when there is no page break:

[image]

And this is the output when the theorem breaks across pages:

[image]

Here is the final complete code:

```
\defineenumeration[THEOREMenumeration]
                  [
                    text=Theorem ,%Space after Theorem is delibrate
                    title=yes,
                    alternative=hanging, 
                    titlestyle=boldslanted, % or bolditalic
                    style=slanted, % or italic
                    width=fit,
                    headcommand=\THEOREMframed,
                 ]

\defineframed     [THEOREMframed]
                  [
                    frame=off,
                    bottomframe=on,
                    location=low,
                    rulethickness=2bp,
                  ]

\definetextbackground [THEOREMframedtext]
                  [
                    mp=ellframe,
                    location=paragraph,
                    leftoffset=1em,
                    topoffset=1.5ex,
                    bottomoffset=1em,
                    rightoffset=0pt,
                    rulethickness=2bp,
                    framecolor=black,
                    before=,
                    after=,
                    strut=no,
                  ]

\startuseMPgraphic{ellframe}
  begingroup;
    interim linecap := butt ;
    for i=1 upto nofmultipars :
      if multikind[i] = "single" :
          draw ( ulcorner multipars[i] -- 
               ( llcorner multipars[i] + (0, boxlineradius )){down} ..
               {right}(llcorner multipars[i] + (boxlineradius, 0) ) --
                 lrcorner multipars[i] )
      elseif multikind[i] = "first" :
          draw leftboundary   multipars[i] 
      elseif multikind[i]= "middle" :
          draw leftboundary  multipars[i] 
      elseif multikind[i]= "last" :
          draw ( ulcorner multipars[i] -- 
               ( llcorner multipars[i] + (0, boxlineradius )){down} ..
               {right}(llcorner multipars[i] + (boxlineradius, 0) ) --
                 lrcorner multipars[i] )
      fi 
      boxlineoptions withpen pencircle scaled boxlinewidth ;
    endfor ;
  endgroup;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\define\starttheorem
  {\dosingleargument\dostarttheorem}

\def\dostarttheorem[#1]%
    {\startTHEOREMenumeration[#1]%
     \page[no]
     \startTHEOREMframedtext
     }

\define\stoptheorem
    {\stopTHEOREMframedtext
     \stopTHEOREMenumeration
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by the Metafun manual (search it for FunnyFrame) and [this thread](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2015/083768.html) on the ConTeXt list. It satisfies some of your queries, but it does not split over pages. I don't know how to do that. Also, it is rather manual. There might be better ways of doing this kind of thing, so see it as a start.

```
\definenumber[ThmNumber][way=bychapter, prefix=no]
\setnumber[ThmNumber][1]


\startuseMPgraphic{FunnyFrame}
picture p ; numeric w, h, o ; path f;
p := textext.rt(\MPstring{ThmTitle}) ;
w := OverlayWidth ; h := OverlayHeight ; o := BodyFontSize ;
p := p shifted (-o,h) ; draw p ;
drawoptions (withpen pencircle scaled 1pt) ;


pair pf;
pf := lrcorner p;
draw lrcorner p -- llcorner p ;
f := (0,ypart pf) -- (0,1mm){down}..{right}(1mm,0)--(w-o,0);
draw f;
setbounds currentpicture to unitsquare xyscaled(w,h) ;
\stopuseMPgraphic


\defineoverlay[FunnyFrame][\useMPgraphic{FunnyFrame}]


\defineframedtext[Thm]
[frame=off,
style=\it,
background=FunnyFrame,
offset=\bodyfontsize,
width=\dimexpr(\textwidth+\bodyfontsize),
before={\blank[line]},
after={\incrementnumber[ThmNumber]\blank}]

\define[2]\FrameTitle%
{\setMPtext{ThmTitle}{\hbox{\hss\strut\bf #1 \namedheadnumber{chapter}.\getnumber[ThmNumber] {\em #2}\hss}}}

\starttext

\chapter{Test chapter}
\setnumber[ThmNumber][1]

\FrameTitle{Theorem}{(Pythagoras)}
\startThm
It holds that
\startformula
a^2+b^2=c^2.
\stopformula
\stopThm
\input Zapf
\FrameTitle{Lemma}{}
\startThm
If $a>b$ and $c>0$ then $ac>bc$. \input tufte\par
\stopThm
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution but only similar to the question.
I use description and frames.

```
    \defineframedtext[styletheoreme]
                     [frame=on,%
                      rulethickness=1mm,%
                      strut=no,%
                      width=0.6\paperwidth,%
                      location=middle,%
                      corner=15,% 
                      toffset=-8mm,% 
                     ]
    \defineframed[titretheoreme]
                     [frame=off,%
                      bottomframe=on,
                      rulethickness=1mm,%
                      width=fit,%
                      location=top,%
                      toffset=-5mm,%
                     ]
    \definedescription[theoreme][width=fit,%
                                 alternative=top,%
                                 headcommand={\hskip -10mm \titretheoreme},%     
                                 before={\startstyletheoreme},%
                                 after={\stopstyletheoreme}%                    
                                  ]


    \starttext
    \starttheoreme{Un théorème}

    Blabla
    \startformula
    \sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}2
    \stopformula
    \stoptheoreme
\stoptext
```

corner=15 is documented in http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Framed#Rounded_Corners
toffset=-8mm allow to lower the frame

You'll have to adjust the dimensions.

It doesn't split over pages.

[image]