# How to renewtheorem and format like this by tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

[image]
[image]

My code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}
%%%%%%%%



\AtBeginEnvironment{ex}{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=black,colback=blue!10,breakable,boxrule=0.5pt,sharp corners]
}
\AtEndEnvironment{ex}{

    \end{tcolorbox}

}
\begin{document}

\begin{ex}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{ex}    

\begin{ex}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{ex}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=Example 1,
    colframe=blue!50!black,colback=blue!10!white,colbacktitle=blue!5!yellow!10!white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=black,attach boxed title to top center=
    {yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    boxed title style={boxrule=0.5mm,
        frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west)
            -- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)
            -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },
        interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)
            -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
            -- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
            -- cycle;} }]
    \lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a `newtcbtheorem` environment like in following code. For some more information about this command look at `theorem` section in `tcolorbox` documentation or in update section of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236230/1952)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{ex}{Example}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=blue!50!black, colback=blue!10!white, colbacktitle=blue!5!yellow!10!white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries, coltitle=black, 
    attach boxed title to top center = {%
        yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    boxed title style={boxrule=0.5mm,
        frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west)
            -- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)
            -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },
        interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)
            -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
            -- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
            -- cycle;}}
    }{ex}

\begin{document}

\begin{ex}{A nice example}{1}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{ex}    

\begin{ex}{}{}
As you can see in theorem~\ref{ex:1}

    \lipsum[2]
\end{ex}

\end{document}
```

[image]