# Is there a way to have the latex code and the packages used, I failed to have these in the pictures please?

Tags: tcolorbox, framed

Here what I captured so far, and I tried to use **\tcbset** to draw the box... and I got a bunch of errors.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: My current code

```
\tcbset{/ .style={
colback=yellow2!, 
enlarge top by=1cm, 
enhance,    
breakable,
boxrule=0pt,        
top=7mm,
drop fuzzy shadow,
overlay unbroken = {\draw[color=red!80!yellow, line width =3pt]
 ([xshift=2pt] frame.north west)--([xshift=2pt] frame.south west);
    \draw[color=red!80!yellow, line width =1pt]
        ( frame.north west)--(frame.north east);
            \node[rectangle] at ([[xshift=1cm, yshift=0.45cm ] frame.north west)
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.06]{imagesInskscape/caracol}};
        \node[rectangle, draw=DeepSkyBlue1, fill=DeepSkyBlue1, 
        font=\LARGE\bfseries, text=white, rounded corners=8pt, minimum width =3cm,
        inner sep=1mm, anchor=north west] at ( [xshift=4cm, yshift=0.3cm] frame.north west){ Example};
    },overlay first ={\draw[color=red!80!yellow, line width =3pt]
        ([xshift=2pt] frame.north west)--([xshift=2pt] frame.south west);
        \draw[color=red!80!yellow, line width =1pt] 
            ( frame.north west)--( frame.north east);
    \node[rectangle] at ([xshift=1cm, yshift=0.45cm ] frame.north west)
{\includegraphics[scale=0.06]{imagesInskscape/caracol}};
    \node[rectangle, draw=DeepSkyBlue1, fill=DeepSkyBlue1, 
font=\LARGE\bfseries, text=white, rounded corners=8pt, minimum width =3cm,
inner sep=1mm, anchor=north west] at ( [xshift=4cm, yshift=0.3cm] frame.north west){ Example};
}, 
overlay middle ={ \draw[color=red!80!yellow!50, line width =3pt]
         ([xshift=2pt] frame.north west)--([xshift=2pt] frame.south west);
        },
overlay last ={\draw[color=red!50!black!50, line width =3pt]
        ( [xshift=3pt] frame.north west)--( [xshift=2pt] frame.north west); }}}
\begin{tcolorbox}[]
    \begin{enumerate}

    \end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure I understand the question. Are you saying that somebody else has produced this and you would like a way to work backwards from the image to the code used to produce it (no that's not possible with current technology, you may have to wait for the singularity) or you would like us to tell you how to do it (in which case ... that's asking kind of a lot)

Comment: I would like to be able to do it and change the code to my way if possible. Thank you to point it out to me.

Comment: It would help if you posted the errors as well.

Comment: Welcome! Please post the code you have got so far - the document which we can compile to reproduce the error. How can we help you change code we have never seen? All we know it contains is `\tcbset`and produces errors-we-know-not-which and which may or may not be related. What is the relation between the two images and those images and your code?

Comment: sorry this is the code below

Comment: Can you expand your code to a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). In particular, the MWE should compile.

Comment: The code is using `tcolorbox` package, so you can start trying to understand similar examples: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184530/1952, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115605/1952,

Comment: Well ! I am going to try it and pace my code afterwards.

Comment: Please tell me you used a template for that \tcbset.  And wherever you got it, don't go there again.

Comment: I got it from a Latex book written in spanish and I used this manual to have inspiration to my documents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\tcbset{
    exstyle/.style={enhanced, colback=Indigo!5, colframe=Indigo, 
                   fonttitle=\bfseries,  
                   colbacktitle=Indigo, coltitle=white,    
                   top=\tcboxedtitleheight,
                   boxed title style={},
                   attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,
                                                   xshift=4mm}%
                   },
    teostyle/.style={enhanced, colback=DarkOrchid!15, colframe=DarkOrchid, 
                   fonttitle=\bfseries, sharp corners, boxrule=0pt,
                   colbacktitle=DarkOrchid, coltitle=white,
                   drop fuzzy shadow,    
                   top=\tcboxedtitleheight,
                   boxed title style={sharp corners},
                   attach boxed title to top left={}%
                   },
}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{miEjemplo}{Ejemplo}{exstyle}{ex}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{miTeorema}{Teorema}{teostyle}{teo}

\begin{document}

\section{Ejemplos}

\begin{miEjemplo}{Un ejemplo}{label}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\emph{\alph*}.)]
\item Si $a=144$ y $b=99$,
\begin{align*}
144 & = 89\cdot 1+55, \text{con resto}\ r_2=55<b=89\\
144 & = 89\cdot 2-34, \text{con resto}\ r_1=34<b=89
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{miEjemplo}

\section{Teoremas}

\begin{miTeorema}{Un teorema}{label}
Sean $a, b\in \mathbb{Z}$ con $b\neq 0$. Sea $q\in \mathbb{Z}$ \dots
\end{miTeorema}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you  @Ignasi and anyone who try to get this code work.