# Putting definitions in color boxes

Tags: math-mode, tcolorbox, colorbox

I've found a awesome document (doing some research in Model Theory).

[image]

I would like to know how I can do those color boxes for definitions, theorems and other stuff. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at the [`tcolorbox`](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) manual, it is very informative

Comment: I'm not so sure about the choice of colours... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myBox}[3][]{
arc=5mm,
lower separated=false,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=green!10,
coltitle=green!50!black,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,
        yshift=-2mm},
colframe=green!50!black,
colback=green!10,
overlay={
\node[draw=green!50!black,thick,
%inner sep=2mm,
fill= green!10,rounded corners=1mm, 
yshift=0pt, 
xshift=-0.5cm, 
left, 
text=green!50!black,
anchor=east,
font=\bfseries] 
at (frame.north east) {#3};},
title=#2,#1}

\begin{document}


\begin{myBox}[]{content}{Some}
content text content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text 
\end{myBox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE: sequence number to the definition**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=subsection]{myBox}[3][]{
arc=5mm,
lower separated=false,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=green!10,
coltitle=green!50!black,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,
        yshift=-2mm},
colframe=green!50!black,
colback=green!10,
overlay={
\node[draw=green!50!black,thick,
%inner sep=2mm,
fill= green!10,rounded corners=1mm, 
yshift=0pt, 
xshift=-0.5cm, 
left, 
text=green!50!black,
anchor=east,
font=\bfseries] 
at (frame.north east) {#3};},
overlay={
\node[draw=green!50!black,thick,
%inner sep=2mm,
fill= green!10,rounded corners=1mm, 
yshift=0pt, 
xshift=-0.5cm, 
left, 
text=green!50!black,
anchor=east,
font=\bfseries] 
at (frame.north east) {#3};},
title=#2 \thetcbcounter,#1}



\begin{document}

\section{section title}
\subsection{subsection title}
\begin{myBox}[]{Content}{Some}
Content text content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text  content text 
\end{myBox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add a sequence number to the defintion and a label to refer back to the definition?

Comment: I think a [`\newtcbtheorem`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184530/1952) box works better in this case than just a regular `\newtcolorbox`